# Writing ASCII character 127 to a PDF file using Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, ascii, itext

I’m having a small issue with a Winforms application I’m developing. I have some global hotkeys that insert some ASCII characters into textboxes. The characters are then written to a PDF file using iTextSharp. This has been working fine, except with one character: the square symbol (#127). The character looks fine in the windows application, but once I write it to the PDF it shows up as a bullet-point, and right on top of whatever character was supposed to come after it (rather than appearing in front of it). I can’t figure out why this happens. All of my other ASCII characters get written to the PDF no problem. Any suggestions?

For reference, this is the character code sheet I am using: http://yorktown.cbe.wwu.edu/sandvig/shared/ASCIICodes.aspx

Here is the code that inserts the character into the form:

```
if(focusedTextbox != null)
{
    if (inKey == 'S')
    {
        focusedTextbox.Text += Convert.ToChar(127);//Square symbol
    }
    else if (inKey == 'P')
    {
        focusedTextbox.Text += Convert.ToChar(177);//Plus-minus symbol
    }
    //Places the cursor after the newly-inserted symbol
    focusedTextbox.Select(focusedTextbox.Text.Length, 0);
}
```

And here is the code that writes the data to the PDF using iTextSharp:

```
//Measurement A
cb.BeginText();
string mesA = mainForm.txtMesA.Text.Trim();
if (mesA.Equals(""))
{
    text = "";
}
else
{
    text = mesA + " " + mainForm.txtUnit.Text;
}
cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, text, offSetStartAt, topRow, 0);
offSetStartAt += colOffset;
cb.EndText();

//Create a PDF page and add the content
PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

//Close the streams
document.Close();
fs.Close();
writer.Close();
reader.Close();
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: ASCII 127 is a [control character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters) - specifically, [Delete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character). Are you sure you should be writing it?

Comment: @raveturned No I'm not sure it's correct, I found it here (trying to insert a square): http://yorktown.cbe.wwu.edu/sandvig/shared/ASCIICodes.aspx The other ones worked flawlessly so I figured this one would too. Do you know the correct code for a square?

Comment: I don't think there is an ASCII chatacter for a square. In my browser, 127 from that list shows as blank - perhaps yours shows a square because font rendering it is trying handle an unsupported character? If you need to render a square, perhaps you could use two square brackets `[]` (code 91 & 93) instead.

Comment: @raveturned your comments qualify for an answer actually, you should post them as such.

Comment: I wasn't sure as I wasn't really answering the question at first. Converted to answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASCII 127 is a [control character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters) - specifically, [Delete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character). Control characters are not intended to be printable.

I don't think there is an ASCII chatacter for a square. In my browser, 127 from the list in the question shows as blank:

[image]

If you see a square it may be the result of your browser's font trying to render an unsupported character.

If you need to render a square, you could use two square brackets `[]` (code 91 & 93) as an approximation instead.